# UniswapV3 swap DAI/USDT issue

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, bignumber, uniswapv3

I'm using single swap implementation from this tutorial: [Single Swaps](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/single-swaps)
(in my hardhat testing environment which is Mainnet fork).

`tokenIn` and `tokenOut` pair of my example is `DAI` and `USDT`.

The `amountIn` parameter that I pass from `test.js` file is BigNumber of DAI tokens.

```
        // Naively set amountOutMinimum to 0. In production, use an oracle or other data source to choose a safer value for amountOutMinimum.
        // We also set the sqrtPriceLimitx96 to be 0 to ensure we swap our exact input amount.
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn, // DAI address
                tokenOut: tokenOut, // USDT address
                fee: 3000, // default
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn, // DAI
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        // The call to `exactInputSingle` executes the swap.
        uint256 amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
```

So when this swap is done the `amountOut` value that I get is strange. For example, if I use
`BigNumber 7706622438316931417300` (~ 7706 DAI), the `amountOut` is `183540559` (~ 183 USDT). But it's incorrect value, because `DAI` price is approximately equal to `USDT`.

**So what is the problem?**

Maybe some of BigNumber-Number conversions are wrong, because of different decimals? Or I just need to use this swap example in some different way?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have enough liquidity? Because there's one point in which no matter how mut tokenIn you pass the tokenOut will remain the same.

Comment: Yea, seems that is the problem. I've tried to reduce the amountIn and results of amountOut are correct. Thanks, man!